# What is the best way to limit the amount of individual folders in an URL so that multiple urls do not reference the same content?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

In php I have a script, that I use mod_rewrite to redirect all calls in a particular url.  For example the mod rewrite rule is something like:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/articles/$1  !-f
RewriteRule ^/articles/(.+)$ /articles/index.php [L]
```

Then my index.php script splits the url into its components and based on the components performs a particular function.

My problem is figuring out how to make the script 404 when people add additional subfolders to the URL. For example, if I have a url like this:

```
http://www.example.com/part/blue-widget/
```

My script will show the blue-widget page.  Now if someone changes the url to read:

```
http://www.example.com/part/blue-widget/another_dir/
```

The script will still show the blue-widget page using this new URL.  What I would like is for the script to instead issue a 404 error. I could have each function check for the amount of components in the URL and if its the right amount, show the content, otherwise issue a 404, but am not sure this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how the code which loads each page works, surely? eg, If each folder is a parameter in a function (like a lot of frameworks), you could compare the amount of folders against the amount of input parameters the function has?

EDIT: Will something like this do?

If you have a set of known parts, you could do:

```
switch ($part) {
    case 'blue-widget':
        // Show blue widget
    break;
    case 'red-widget':
        // Show redwidget
    break;
    case 'yellow-widget':
        // Show yellow widget
    break;
    default:
       header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
       header("Location: xxx");
}
```

Comment: I have been doing it by using the first part of the path as the indicator as to what should happen in the script.  If "part" is the first subfolder, then the next subfolder should be the part name and it should be pulled form the DB and displayed.

Unfortunately, a user could simply add another subfolder to the end of the url and the part would still show with a normal 200 error.  This is probably not good for SEO.  I could prob fix fix that with canonical tags pointing to the legitimate article, but I was hoping for a way in PHP to make it so that if the extra subfolder is found, it 404s.

Comment: Unfortunately not, because I could have 1000s of parts. Therefore a switch statement would not be realistic unfortunately.  Basically what I am doing is switch statement for the first part of the path. Part = show_part(). Feed = show_feed(), etc.  Then in the show_part function is specify a maximum amount of components of the url and if its greater than 2 (/part/blue-widget/) then 404 it, otherwise show the part.  I just was not sure if this was the most efficient way of doing it.